# apache access.log requests from localhost to localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, php, spam-prevention

My server is spamming via postfix from www-data user.

In apache access.log:

```
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:24:01 +0300] "GET /treningi.php HTTP/1.0" 200 21025 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:23:56 +0300] "POST /public/files/__DxS_NEWDIR__a3X/nd24f62.php HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:24:31 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 9499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://  www.google.com/bot.html)"
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:25:08 +0300] "POST /public/files/__DxS_NEWDIR__a3X/nd24f62.php HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:25:36 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 9499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 YaBrowser/13.10.1500.9323 Safari/537.36"
90.156.208.121 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:25:46 +0300] "GET /novostibankov.php HTTP/1.0" 200 28410 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 YaBrowser/13.10.1500.9323 Safari/537.36"
```

Server IP is 90.156.208.121.
"POST /public/files/__DxS_NEWDIR__a3X/nd24f62.php" is request by spambot, but it shown from server IP.

But 20/Jan/2014:17:25:46 +0300 is my request from YaBrowser, not from server!

Why is it shown from the server IP, not mine?

Some request shown not from the server:

10.16.24.221 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:05:28 +0300] "GET /main.php HTTP/1.0" 200 9499

> "http:// www.DOMAIN.ru/generatepasswordpage.php" "Opera/9.80 (Windows
>   NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"
>   10.16.24.221 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:05:31 +0300] "GET /r_vse.php HTTP/1.0" 200 14623 "http:// www.DOMAIN.ru/main.php" "Opera/9.80
>   (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"
>   10.16.24.221 - - [20/Jan/2014:17:05:42 +0300] "GET /myrich.php HTTP/1.0" 200 11449 "http:// www.DOMAIN.ru/r_vse.php" "Opera/9.80
>   (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"

Answer (score 0):

Per http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-10048/product_id-17956/version_id-81261/Nginx-Nginx-0.6.32.html the version of nginx you are running may be vulnerable to a remote code execution exploit, and someone may have broken into your machine. I would recommend backing up any important files, and then completely reinstalling the OS on your VPS to remove any backdoors that may have been placed on your machine.